# Telnet session, fork vs. thread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, fork, telnet

My program should serve multiple telnet sessions (in fact multiple tcp connections). Each telnet session should serve multiple ssh connections. What is better: each telnet connection = fork or new thread? The same question for ssh connection. What is less problematic?

Comment: http://www.geekride.com/fork-forking-vs-threading-thread-linux-kernel/

Comment: "Each telnet session should serve multiple ssh connections".   Can you clarify; taken at face value this doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

In case of using fork you will have separate processes. It takes more resources from OS.

In case of using threads all will be in one process and will be less problem with communication and control between threads.